# jQuery height problem

Tags: jquery

Probably error, my jQuery/JS isn't all that. Any ideas how to make this work? Currently it is correctly setting the background colour, but the height remains the same :(

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var inside_height = $(".inside").height() - 500;
    $(".artists").height(inside_height).css(backgroundColor:"green"});
});
</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why is there a curly bracket after green?

Comment: What's the value of inside_height? How many objects with the class "inside" are there? If more than one, does height() just return the first height, or do you want to do this for more than one? Can we see the HTML it's operating on?

Comment: There is only one height. The problem is the line below I believe, because if I replace inside_height with a numerical value, it still won't set the height.

Comment: @phoenix: You can apparently use a hash in the css() call, just looks like he left off the opening bracket.

Comment: @James: What if you remove everything else, and just try $(".artists").height("100px")? What does it do then?

Comment: can you show your markup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `$(window).load(function())` instead.

Change it to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
    var inside_height = $(".inside").height() - 500;
    $(".artists").height(inside_height).css(backgroundColor:"green"});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var inside_height = $(".inside").height() - 500;
    $(".artists").height(inside_height).css("background-color", "green");
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this Example may Help you!

Js:

```
 $j(document).ready(function(){
  var inside_height = $(".inside").height() - 500;
  $(".artists").height(inside_height).css({backgroundColor:"green"});
 });
```

css:

```
.inside{
    width:100px;
    Height:600px;
    background:#000;
    float:left;
} 
.artists{
    width:100px;
    float:left;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="inside"></div>
<div class="artists"></div>
```